# Getting error in factory method using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am getting the following error while calling one function using factory method using angular.js.

```
   TypeError: focusField.clearBorderColor is not a function
        at n.$scope.clearField (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/controller/profileController.js:142:14)
        at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:212:283), <anonymous>:4:242)
        at f (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:252:485)
        at n.$eval (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:132:452)
        at n.$apply (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:133:175)
        at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:253:36)
        at HTMLInputElement.m.event.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:8549)
        at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:4:5252)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
var dashboard = angular.module('Channabasavashwara');

dashboard.controller('profileController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $window, $state, focusField) {
    $scope.buttonName = "Add";
    $scope.addProfileData = function (billdata) {
        //console.log('button name',$scope.buttonName);
        if ($scope.buttonName == "Add") {
            if (billdata.$valid) {
                if ($scope.colgname == null || $scope.colgname == '') {
                    alert('College Title field could not be blank...');
                    focusField.borderColor('procolgtitle');
                } else if ($scope.shortname == null) {
                    alert('subtitle field could not be blank...');
                } else if ($scope.address == null) {
                    alert('Address field could not be blank...');
                } else if ($scope.contno == null) {
                    alert('Contact no field could not be blank...');
                } else if ($scope.colgemail == null) {
                    alert('Email address field could not be blank...');
                } else if ($scope.colgcode == null) {
                    alert('college code field could not be blank...');
                } else {
                    var userdata = {
                        'colg_name': $scope.colgname,
                        'colg_shname': $scope.shortname,
                        'address': $scope.address,
                        'cont_no': $scope.contno,
                        'email': $scope.colgemail,
                        'code': $scope.colgcode
                    };
                    //console.log('userdata',userdata);
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: "php/profile/addProfileData.php",
                        data: userdata,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        console.log('profile', response);
                        alert(response.data['msg']);
                        $scope.colgname = null;
                        $scope.address = null;
                        $scope.contno = null;
                        $scope.shortname = null;
                        $scope.colgemail = null;
                        $scope.colgcode = null;
                        $scope.profileData.unshift(response.data);
                        //$state.go('dashboard.profile',{}, { reload: true });
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert(response.data['msg']);
                        $state.go('dashboard.profile', {}, {reload: true})
                    })
                }
            } else {
                alert('This form is not valid');
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.clearField = function (id) {
        focusField.clearBorderColor(id);
    }
});
```

I am getting error in `$scope.clearField` function.I can execute `focusField.borderColor('procolgtitle');` properly.In this function i am not getting any error.But when the `clearField` function is called it is throwing the above error.

```
dashboard.factory('focusField', function ($timeout, $window) {
    return {
        borderColor: function (id) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
                if (element) {
                    element.focus();
                    element.style.borderColor = "red";
                }
            });
        },
        clearBorderColor: function (id) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
                console.log('ele', element);
                if (element) {
                    element.style.borderColor = "#555555";
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Any chance you have more than one `focusField` provider registered?

Comment: No,I have used this where i am requiring this.here i am using to call two function from factory method.

Comment: When I look on your site, the `focusField` provider **only** has a `borderColor` method. Maybe you forgot to upload an updated script file?

Comment: @Phil : ok by changing its name now its working.

Comment: @Phil :`focusField.clearBorderColor(id);` this was onther method.